# Can't figure out why I get App Engine flex "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Google\Protobuf\Internal\bccomp()"

Tags: php, google-app-engine, composer-php, google-text-to-speech, bcmath

I'm trying to implement Google's Text-To-Speech API on App Engine flex environment, but get this error:

> "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined
>   function Google\Protobuf\Internal\bccomp() in
>   /app/web/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:941"

Once I solved the problem by requiring BCmath() in my composer.json

```
{  
    "require": {
        "ext-bcmath": "*",
        "google/cloud-text-to-speech": "^1.0",
        "google/gax": "^1.3",
         "grpc/grpc": "^1.4",
         "google/auth": "^1.8",
         "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^2.0",
         "google/protobuf": "^3.11"        
    }
}
```

Then after reinstalling /vendor I can't get rid of the error message. I tried to install the BCmath extension by running

```
sudo apt install php7.2-bcmath
```

But it says that the extension is already installed.
I run also this
php -i | grep -i bcmath
And get this message

> /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini, bcmath BCMath support =>
>   enabled bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

The test for bccomp()

```
php -r "echo bccomp('1', '2');"
```

I get '-1' as supposed to be. It looks like the function works.

I even tried to enable the BCmath extention in php.ini

```
extension=bcmath.so
```

I placed the .ini file in the same directory as my /vendor and index.php. Still, after deployment the app by

```
gcloud app deploy
```

I still get the fatal error.

Comment: Are you sure that bcmath is enabled in your FPM? Check the fpm's php.ini

Comment: @Mihail0v Could you please elaborate a bit how to check FPM and enable bcmath there from Google Cloud Shell?

Comment: /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini it supposed to be here by default. Check that file contains "extensions=bcmath.so" section.

Comment: @Mihail0v there is no such directory as /fpm. When I'm in /etc/php/7.2/ directory it shows only 'cgi'  'cli'  and 'mods-available' subdirectories. In /mods-available there is a bcmath.ini file and its content is "; configuration for php bcmath module
; priority=20
extension=bcmath.so". php.ini is in /cli directory and I didn't find bcmath extesion. So, how to add it ti php.ini?

Comment: @TechToSpeech Sorry, I thought you using php-fpm. You can pass phpinfo();exit; at the begining of index.php to see your available extensions and php.ini path. Does it shows that bcmath is enabled ?

Comment: @Mihail0v I found php.ini in /etc/php/7.2/cli directory and bcmath is NOT there among other extensions. So, how I enable it in my php.ini?

Comment: Based on your question, you have already enabled bcmath for 7.2-cli. But It looks like that your index.php runs not by php-cli. So thats why you should try check phpinfo() runned by your index.php and check that it shows bcmath enabled.

Comment: @Mihail0v I just run phpinfo(). In the 'Configure Command ' section I found this: '--enable-bcmath=shared'. The php.ini path is /opt/php72/lib/php.ini, but for some reasons I can't enter further than /opt, as Cloud Shell complains that the  /opt/php72/lib/ directory doesn't exists.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/phpseclib/bcmath_compat

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After 5days of breaking head, solution was found. It appears that BCMath is installed in PHP versions >= 7, but NOT enabled on Google App Engine. To enable it I did the following:

> 1. I have created php.ini file and placed it in the same directory as app.yaml  file, which might be different from the root directory of your app 
>      (index.php for example).
> 2. In empty newly created php.ini have added one  line:

```
extension=bcmath
```

Then require it in composer.json

```
{
    "require": {

        "ext-bcmath": "*"  
    }
}
```

Finally deploy the project

```
 gcloud app deploy
```

And that's all!

Comment: Thanks. This issue also been discuss in [Github](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/4284).

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error from a docker environment, try adding the following to your Dockerfile (it fixed the issue for me).

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
```

More details here: https://forums.docker.com/t/php-bcmath-extension-doesnt-get-installed-in-dockerfile/99773