# Google Analytics Data API (GA4) - Not working on live site

Tags: php, google-analytics-data-api

I am using the new Google Analytics Data API and have it working great on my local machine, however, when I publish the code to the live site I don't get any errors, the page just stops loading after the runReport call.

I'm using a service account to pull the data.

Is there any kind of domain restrictions on service accounts?

Answer (score 0):

After a little research, I went in and checked the error logs on my server since I wasn't getting any frontend errors. I was seeing the below message:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Google\Protobuf\Internal\bccomp()

This thread helped resolve the issue! My server didn't have bcmath PHP package, once installed following the below stackoverflow thread it was fixed!
[Can't figure out why I get App Engine flex "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Google\Protobuf\Internal\bccomp()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805958/cant-figure-out-why-i-get-app-engine-flex-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-fu)

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by upgrading my PHP version to the latest.